# maxlength is not working in joomla 2.5 form fields

Tags: joomla, maxlength

I am having an issue when using below code in plugin xml in Joomla 2.5 version.

***maxlength is not working.***

```
<field name="phone" type="text" default="" label="Phone" 
description="Phone: Must not be greater than 13 numbers" maxlength="13" />
```

or

```
<param name="phone" type="text" default="" label="Phone" 
description="Phone: Must not be greater than 13 numbers" maxlength="13" />
```

Please let me know what need to be done or i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using the first bit of code you've provided in your extension as Joomla 2.5 uses `<field>`, not `<param>`.

So once you have many any changes to the XML file, you need to ensure you open the Plugin in the Joomla backend, and click "Save" which will apply any changes made.

Comment: Basically this plugin is for virtuemart's vmpayment plugin. i have used both <field> and <param>.

Comment: And as mentioned, after editing the XML file, did you click the "save" button?

Comment: I got the issue. In libraries\joomla\html\parameter\element\text.php in function fetchElement the maxlength attribute was missing. i have added it. may be its joomla version issue. but i have fixed it now.

Comment: Please can you submit this bug to Joomla's Github page as I;m sure they will fix this in the next release :)

Comment: There was no maxlength attribute until very recently.  Also just use the tel field type and related rule and filter and it will all be taken care of much more cleanly.